# I'm trying to write query to fetch month name in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2012

My database has months stored in `01,02,..,12` format. This query is not able to read 01,02

Please help me to make correction so that query can take month 01 as January and so on.

```
left(MonthName(left(Fields!Month.Value,2)),3)+" ' "+right(Fields!Month.Value
```

Comment: complete your code please..

Comment: This is partial SSRS Code.

Answer (score 0):

left(MonthName(MONTH(left(Fields!Month.Value,2))),3)+" ' "+right(Fields!Month.Value

MonthName takes an INT as a parameter, not a string.  So "01" will not work but 1, will

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty solution might be to create a date so that you can use the built-in date functions.

```
dateadd(MM,Fields!Month.Value-1,convert(date,'1900-01-01',120))
```

then to get the name of the month you could use

```
datename(MM,dateadd(MM,Fields!Month.Value-1,convert(date,'1900-01-01',120)))
```